# KDE Neon refuses to install anything after installing pipewire with dependency install failure

Tags: dependencies, ubuntu-22.04, kde-neon

I have a problem with installing ANY new app on my brand new laptop of which I just installed Ubuntu-22.04-based KDE Neon. After trying to install pipewire, the dependencies for it keep failing to install and I now cannot install any new apps even if they are not pipewire. This applies for all apps in every repository in existence.
Here are the error messages after trying to install any app; including pipewire:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

after `sudo apt` anything.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pipewire-bin_0.3.71-2~ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/pipewire-pulse.1.gz', which is also in package pipewire-pulse 0.3.48-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pipewire-bin_0.3.71-2~ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

after executing `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg -r pipewire-pulse
```

Comment: Its best to explain why this works.

Comment: I initially made a misinput, but in the end it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just wanted to be unblocked and the solution worked like a charm, thank you!